# Who are these characters referenced in chapter 4 of Spotted Flower?

Tags: spotted-flower

**What are the characters referenced in the screenshot below, and what game(s) do they come from?**

[image: Characters from games]

*You can ignore the rest below - they are purely for informational purpose.*

---

In chapter 4 of Spotted Flower<sup>1</sup>, in the scene where the granny suggests a name for the baby, she made references to the names of the girls in anime, and dating-sim games. Listing them in order of mention:

- The surnames (Kaname, Miki, Tomoe, Sakura, Akemi) and then the first names (Madoka, Sayaka, Mami, Kyouko, Homura) of the 5 girls in [Puella Magi Madoka Magica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puella_Magi_Madoka_Magica): Kaname Madoka (鹿目 まどか), Miki Sayaka (美樹 さやか), Tomoe Mami (巴 マミ), Sakura Kyōko (佐倉 杏子), Akemi Homura (暁美 ほむら).
- The first names (Manaka, Rinko, Nene) of the 3 heroines in [LovePlus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LovePlus): Takane Manaka (高嶺 愛花), Kobayakawa Rinko (小早川 凛子), Anegasaki Nene (姉ヶ崎 寧々).
- Then the characters in the screenshot I put up, which I cannot identify.
- Then the first name of 4 girls (Yui, Kyouko, Chinatsu, Ayano) from [Yuru Yuri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YuruYuri): Toshinou Kyouko (歳納 京子), Funami Yui (船見 結衣), Yoshikawa Chinatsu (吉川 ちなつ), Sugiura Ayano (杉浦 綾乃).

  The protagonist noticed that the granny made sure to leave out Akaza Akari (赤座 あかり).

<sub><sup>1</sup> It is a story of a newlywed working otaku and his pregnant wife.</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're from a *Visual Novel* called **[Kizuato](http://vndb.org/v184)**. The names are (in order of their pictures):

[image]
Kashiwagi Hatsune (柏木 初音)

[image]
Kashiwagi Kaede (柏木 楓)

[image]
Kashiwagi Azusa (柏木 梓)

[image]
Kashiwagi Chizuru (柏木 千鶴)

As for "Kashiwagi Azusa"'s name (柏木 梓), I'm not sure why it was translated as "Azuki", but if you look at the original Japanese:

[image]

It says "Azusa".

Comment: It's very likely that "Azuki" is a mistake by the translators. The furigana き and さ are similar enough that an inexperienced translator or someone who just wasn't paying attention might make that mistake, especially since Azuki is also a common female name which is sometimes written in ways involving 梓.